# Fast way of scanning 50,000+ images directory with php

Tags: php

My images are organized by product id.
XX-1.jpg
XX-2.jpg
XX-3.jpg

To find the images of 1 product, I use the following method.

```
$all_images[$resolution]=glob("/home/imgimportsinc/public_html/sharing/images_by_product_id/{$resolution}/*.jpg");
```

And then I look for the product id in the array.
I do have a cron job that does the above and cache stores the image urls for each product so that I don't have to scan for the images each time.

Am I doing it right or is there a more fast/accurate/proper way of doing this?

Comment: Well, if they are stored using the product ID then shouldn't it just be a matter of creating the path? Why do you need to search for them? Are they not there already?

Comment: ^^ and or store product image file name\location in the database with the product

Comment: I need to scan it because what if I upload a new picture at a later time or what if I delete a picture. There's no other way for me to tell if an image exists or not unless I actually record that in the database

Comment: you always have the id just use glob for `ID-*.jpg`

Comment: Why not just `if (file_exists('/path/to/'.$id.'-1.jpg')) { do stuff...`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for this

```
$dirname = "/home/imgimportsinc/public_html/sharing/";
$images = glob($dirname."*{$resolution}-*.{$extention}");
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the comment's are already giving you hints, that less searching will result in less computation time. If you could just keep track of deletion/insertion, you can just build the paths on the fly with the ids.

Another small hint, using  ***GLOB_NOSORT*** as a flag could significantly decrease the computation time, if you don't need the elements sorted.